# Passing the Values of an array to a function (not the array itself)

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters, extract

I have a function that has 5 requqired parameters and 2 optional ones.
So a user can input 5-7 parameters and they are stored inside of an array. How can I pass those values to the function, is there something similar like extract() that returns the values and not the numbers?

E.g.:

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
functionname($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2],$arr[3],$arr[4],$arr[5])
```

doesn't work, because I never know for sure if the sixth parameter really exists.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) fit the bill?

Comment: Check out the [spread operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-163)

Comment: Have a look at argument unpacking
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Comment: Sure it does, thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments problem is solved ;)

Comment: @ChrisHaas in PHP it's **splat** operator.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver, I stand corrected and I can guarantee that by tomorrow I'll forget it once again!